# What is purification process of chandala to change to shudra?

Tags: caste-system, varnashrama, chandala

How chandala change his varna to shudra ? What purification process is mentioned in scripture ?

Comment: A question of how anyone in general could become a Shudra would be more useful, especially since it is doubtful a scripture would go into enough detail to detail each case.